# How do I select text without an ID in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
  <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="icon1"></a> | <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" id="icon2"></a> | <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" id="icon3"></a> |  This is the text I want to select and style specifically.
</div>
```

I would like to do this in HTML/CSS. No jQuery or Javascript.

Also...I would like to do this without using another `<div>` tag, because it throws off the presentation.

Edit: For clarification, I can't apply the style to 'compv-navbar' because essentially I would like to 'enclose' that specific text. I would like to be able to style it as if it were it's own div, without the div. If I were to style the entire compv-navbar div, it would do all the pipes (|) and I don't want that. I just want that specific piece of text to be styled.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried and what issues have you had? Does this not meey you needs? #compv-navbar{ /*your style here*/}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap that text in a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, then apply styles to `#compv_navbar span` instead. `<span>` is a generic inline element, so it *should not* throw off your layout.

Here's an illustration, assuming the pipe separators *aren't* part of the text you want to target:

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
  <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="icon1"></a> | 
  <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" id="icon2"></a> | 
  <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" id="icon3"></a> |  
  <span>Text to be styled</span>
</div>
```

<del>If you want the separators to be styled the same way, perhaps using `<span>` wouldn't fit the description of 'simple' anymore (wrapping the separators in the same span tags, or whatever), in which case I'd just go with styling `#compv_navbar`.</del>

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a simple span tag.  Why make this more complicated than it has to be?  KISS.

Comment: I knew that there was some simple HTML structure that allowed me to do this, without throwing off the layout, I just couldn't remember what it was.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How bout the following selectors?

`#icon3:after`

`:not(.icon1,.icon2,.icon3)`

Or I like BoltClock's use `<span>` suggestion

:contains() does what you want but it's deprecated as of CSS3 I think